# zend framework 2 how to disable view template execute global function?

Tags: zend-framework2

in the layout/layout.phtml.

I can run this dangerous php function.

```
<?php
eval("phpinfo();");
file_put_contents("public/phpinfo.php", "<?php phpinfo(); ");
?>
```

How can I disable the global functions? and must be use function defined in view plugins, means must started $this->function() instead of function();

Answer (score 0):

this is impossible. Template engine in zf2 is based on PHP. If you need block this functions, you must change template engine to ex. Smarty.